# Autofill framework updates 8.1 cause crash to EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I updated my phone to 8.1 from 8.0 and now I am getting this crash when I am trying to tap any EditText or com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText on my app (which is built with API Level 25).

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                              
java.lang.NullPointerException: activityToken
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2010)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
at android.view.autofill.IAutoFillManager$Stub$Proxy.startSession(IAutoFillManager.java:381)
at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.startSessionLocked(AutofillManager.java:993)
at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewEntered(AutofillManager.java:595)
at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewEntered(AutofillManager.java:566)
at android.view.View.notifyEnterOrExitForAutoFillIfNeeded(View.java:6980)
at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:6966)
at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:9606)
at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:6631)
at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:10868)
at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:10847)
at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:10814)
at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:10756)
at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:13018)
at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:9665)
at com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText.onTouchEvent(MaterialEditText.java:1501)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11776)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:448)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1829)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3307)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:410)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12015)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4795)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4293)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4350)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6661)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6635)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6596)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6764)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

The layout is as follows:

```
 <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                    android:id="@+id/usernameET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_xlarge"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_large"
                    android:enabled="@{!loading}"
                    android:hint="@string/username"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal"
                    app:met_accentTypeface="fonts/averta_bold.otf"
                    app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
                    app:met_floatingLabelText="@string/username"
                    app:met_primaryColor="@color/text_dark"
                    app:met_textColor="@color/text_blue"
                    app:met_typeface="fonts/averta_regular.otf" />
```

Can you please advise why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 13):

I had similiar problem. Same error when tapping on *EditText*, on field in *Webview*. 
In my case the problem was using wrong *Context* within *attachBaseContext* method.

Old code

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
   super.attachBaseContext(applicationContext.createConfigurationContext(...))
}
```

Fixed code:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase.createConfigurationContext(...))
}
```

No more errors with Autofill framework. I suggest checking if you didn't make similar mistake missusing Context.

Comment: Nice! this solved my issue with autofill crashes on android 8.1 webviews. But still don't really understand why this happens, and only in this specific version of android. Any ideas why?

Comment: Great answer! I would never found the culprit myself. The place where the crash happens have nothing to do with the place where the problem starts. You Save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 6):

Seems like a straight-up regression bug to me. I'm taking the most pragmatic approach possible by doing this in the Activity.onCreate:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
  getWindow().getDecorView().setImportantForAutofill(
      View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO_EXCLUDE_DESCENDANTS);
}
```

Comment: you can also add `android:importantForAutofill="no"` in xml and suppress lint for warning to apply a cleaner fix :)

Answer (score 1):

i spend time on this error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: activityToken
       at android.os.Parcel.readException + 2010(Parcel.java:2010)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException + 1950(Parcel.java:1950)
       at android.view.autofill.IAutoFillManager$Stub$Proxy.startSession + 397(IAutoFillManager.java:397)
```

Solution:

```
android:importantForAutofill="no" in XML file in Edit Text.
```