# React Native fatal crashes on clicking textInput

Tags: android, react-native

I get the exact crash listed in this issue: 
[Autofill framework updates 8.1 cause crash to EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763756/autofill-framework-updates-8-1-cause-crash-to-edittext)

However I have a react-native project. Because it dynamically creates views it is impractical to add the fix listed on that issue. The fix is per View.

Does anyone know a solution that may work for a React Native project?

Our app is working in all phones except Samsung S8/9 (on Oreo 8.0) where it crashes whenever anyone clicks on any TextInput.

Here is the exact error I am getting:

[image: Error with Package name redacted]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we fixed this by upgrading to React Native 0.56 and updating all our libraries and dependencies. This caused a whole host of other issues because you have to upgrade everything to use Babel 7. Our jest tests are still not working.

Comment: to avoid the babel issue, you could downgrade to RN 0.55.4. We ended up deciding to hold of on upgrading to 56 as a few dependencies were breaking for this reason

Comment: In other words, if your dependencies aren't compatible, revert to versions where they were compatible and keep an eye on the repos. When someone updates the dependency in question to fix the issue, update the version you're using. If you lose patience and it's taking too long, contribute to the project and make a pull request!

Comment: @nunchucks we need RN 0.56 to be able to fix the issue with crashing inputs so that isn't an option

Comment: @Nunchucks we have forked about 10 repos now and are testing them. We may put in some pull requests on them as well once testing is complete